# Is there a way to assert and fail a request after polling in karate?

Tags: karate

I have a request where i get Processing or Submitted in a response parameter if the request is in process or passed respectively.
I am able to poll and get if the status is "Processing" or"Submitted" but after that I am unable to fail the request if still i am not getting the expected status after polling for 5 times.
How can i fail request after certain retries do not provide me expected response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question,

I assume you are polling using a js function, 
If so you can add a boolean `return` from that, if you condition not met `return false` or if condition met `return true`  then assert the value returned from your feature file.

```
* def pollingFunc =
"""
function(x) {
     // your polling logic which retrives status
     if (status == x) {
      return true;
     } 
     else{
      return false;
     } 
} 
"""
```

In feature

```
* def statusFound = pollingFunc("Processed" )
* assert (statusFound == true)
```

If the expected status not obtained after polling the `assert` will fail the test