How to retry a karate code that is connecting to Database for five times?
So I have these requirements:

I am running a karate feature file where I am hitting an API and getting a variable called offset in the response. I extract this offset variable and save it as offset.
I am establishing a db connection in the same feature file and then running a database query which is suppossed to return me a non-empty array.
If the db query returns an empty array, I will re-run the db query for at most 5 times and I will stop once I receive the array size> 0 and I will save it into a variable so that I can use that in next step in my feature file.
Even after 5 retries if the array size returned from db is 0, I will go on with normal execution of the feature file steps

I tried something like this:
* url "https://myurl.com"
* method POST
* print response

* def offset = response.offset

#This is the line of code which I need to run for at most 5 times until I receive the non-empty array
* def customerSummary = db.runQuery( "SELECT * FROM [PBH.ZAFFIN] where offset= " + offset )

So after this my code should behave like
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   if(customerSummary.length =0){
       run DB query again and check if it's more than 0;
       continue(if it' not more than 0);
    }
   else
       save the value in some variable to be used in the same feature file and break loop
}

Please tell me how to implement that? Just we need to make sure I am able to access the customerSummary variable again in the same feature file to make further validations.

I really think this is not really related to karate, work with a good programmer if needed to implement the logic in db.runQuery(), your question is incomplete without mentioning the language and without all the code involved

also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53535359/143475 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/74217472/143475

I don't think so because I need that retry query strictly in the karate feature file so that if it returns the value I can reuse it in feature file

ok @PeterThomas Can you atleast tell me how to run karate code within javascript function ?

then follow the second link and look at the example, especially this one: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/polling/polling.feature
